# Iterating a function with multiple arguments over different variables with R

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

I have a dataset with 50 observations over 10 variables and I would like to apply the following function over the all variable permutations.

```
new_fun <- function(data, x, y) {
  x <- data[ , x]
  y <- data[ , y]
  value <- (x - y) / (x + y)
  colnames(value) <- paste(names(x), "/", names(y), sep = "")
  return(value)
}
```

here is a part of the dataset

```
var1    var2    var3    var4    var5    var6    var7    var8    var9    var10
1268    1522    1268    1842    4728    5611    5544    2374    1535    5773
1286    1534    1259    1829    4834    5802    5776    2383    1538    5928
1296    1534    1266    1853    4905    5805    5916    2418    1545    5949
1296    1488    1239    1791    4963    5985    5880    2359    1524    6142
1273    1503    1228    1787    4694    5608    5608    2268    1476    5725
1290    1522    1271    1811    4799    5728    5752    2402    1555    5832
1265    1510    1247    1786    4981    6072    6172    2409    1526    6258
1289    1527    1246    1841    4876    5827    5808    2361    1522    6009
1322    1590    1351    1917    4532    5271    5264    2412    1589    5418
1334    1589    1445    1899    3680    4638    4820    2321    1638    4974
1347    1532    1370    1865    3618    4702    4852    2275    1619    4994
```

The idea is to have a new dataset with 50 observations on 90 columns (n=10, r=2, no repeats).

```
     var1/var2   var1/var3   var1/var4  ...
1       .            .           .      ...
2       .            .           .      ...
3       .            .           .      ...
.       .            .           .      ...
.       .            .           .      ...
.       .            .           .      ...
```

I have tried apply functions and loops with no success so far. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a mock data set. You will have more chance for people to understand and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `tidyverse` and the `purrr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

# the data you provided
varst <- as.data.frame(read_csv("var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10
1268,1522,1268,1842,4728,5611,5544,2374,1535,5773
1286,1534,1259,1829,4834,5802,5776,2383,1538,5928
1296,1534,1266,1853,4905,5805,5916,2418,1545,5949
1296,1488,1239,1791,4963,5985,5880,2359,1524,6142
1273,1503,1228,1787,4694,5608,5608,2268,1476,5725
1290,1522,1271,1811,4799,5728,5752,2402,1555,5832
1265,1510,1247,1786,4981,6072,6172,2409,1526,6258
1289,1527,1246,1841,4876,5827,5808,2361,1522,6009
1322,1590,1351,1917,4532,5271,5264,2412,1589,5418
1334,1589,1445,1899,3680,4638,4820,2321,1638,4974
1347,1532,1370,1865,3618,4702,4852,2275,1619,4994"))

map_dfc(names(varst), # cycle through each column
        function(x) {         
          # fetch all columns beside x to match
          map(setdiff(names(varst), x),
              function(y){ # your function as above
                v_x <- varst[x]
                v_y <- varst[y]
                ret <- (v_x - v_y) / (v_x + v_y)
                names(ret) <- paste0(x, "/", y)
                ret # return the caluclated values
              })
        })
```

[image: results]

## to stop repeats

To stop comparing `var2/var1` if `var1/var2` has already been compared, etc. do the following:

```
# if you need to put the column names in order, use this
# you'll also need two digit number names, e.g. var01, var07, var10
# varst <- varst %>% select(order(colnames(varst)))

map_dfc(names(varst)[-length(names(varst))], # map each column except the final column as x
        function(x) {         
          # fetch all columns after x in the df column names
          map(names(varst)[(match(x,names(varst))+1):length(names(varst))],
              function(y){ # your function as above
                if(!is.na(y)){
                  v_x <- varst[x]
                  v_y <- varst[y]
                  ret <- (v_x - v_y) / (v_x + v_y)
                  names(ret) <- paste0(x, "/", y)
                  ret # return the caluclated values
                }

              })
        })
```

Comment: What if i wanted to change from permutation to combinations of variables?

Comment: Can you give detail on what that would like like?

Comment: the way it is working right now I am getting every permutation of variables possible with the exception of repeated ones like (var2/ var2), but it still assumes order is important so i get (var1/var2) and (var2/var1). What I am looking for is unique combinations of variables, as such, assuming (var1/var2) and (var2/var1) are the same thing.

Comment: instead of line `map(setdiff(names(varst), x),`, use: `map(names(varst)[(match("var8",names(varst))+1):length(names(varst))])`

Comment: That worked, but it still gives me var10/var10 instead of stopping at the last unique combination. So I have all 45 unique combos, plus var10/var10, so 46.

Comment: have updated the answer to strip out matching the final `var10` column with itself. I also added a `order` command to put the columns in order, but you'll need to rename all the `var#` as `var##` for this to work, or `var###` depending on how many columns you have